# Помогите исправить ошибку при импорте pyowm

Tags: python, импорт, pyowm

Вот ошибка

```
 from pyowm import OWM

ImportError: cannot import name 'OWM' from partially initialized module 'pyowm' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyowm\__init__.py)
```

Вот код:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ua'
place = input("Введите ваш город: ")

owm = OWM("my api")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
my_weather= observation.weather
mywind = my_weather.wind()
my_temp=my_weather.temperature('celsius')
print(my_temp)
print(mywind)
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы свой скрипт назвали `pyowm.py`, также как называется библиотека, из-за этого импорт правильно не работает. Переименуйте свой скрипт во что-нибудь другое.

Comment: мой скрипт називается 2.py

Comment: Может у вас рядом не этот, так другой скрипт с таким именем лежит? Ошибка "partially initialized module 'pyowm' (most likely due to a circular import)" обычно именно в таком случае возникает.

Comment: y меня нигде нету таких названий

Comment: Попробуйте тогда поискать на этом сайте ответы по строке "pyowm", там много чего может быть, может какой-то из готовых ответов поможет, я помню было очень много вопросов-ответов уже тут.

Comment: Ошибка возникает из-за проблемы с импортом модуля OWM из pyowm. Она обычно возникает из-за циклического импорта (один модуль пытается импортировать другой, который уже пытается импортировать первый)
Как варинт попробовать изменить порядок импорта

Comment: Какая используемая версия pyowm и откуда/как устанавливали?

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь я просто переустановил py owm и заработало